# C# console aplication add rows to Excel with msgraph5.x

Tags: c#, excel, microsoft-graph-api

In the example from site of Microsoft I have this:

```
var requestBody = new microsoft.Graph.Drives.Item.Items.Item.Workbook.Tables.Item.Rows.Add.AddPostRequestBody
{
    Index = 5,
    Values = new List<List<1>>
    {
        new List<1>
        {
            1,
            2,
            3,
        },
        new List<4>
        {
            4,
            5,
            6,
        },
    },
};
var result = await graphClient.Drives["{drive-id}"].Items["{driveItem-id}"].Workbook.Tables["{workbookTable-id}"].Rows.Add.PostAsync(requestBody);
```

but obviously not work, the syntax is incorrect. I can't find the correct format of the data to declare the values to add.

Comment: Working with Excel file is still not supported in SDK v5. Many bugs already reported. Similar bug to yours: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/1928

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a `new List<1>`.

When you see angle brackets after a type name, it indicates that the type is a [generic type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/generics) and expects the name of another type (called the type parameter) between the angle brackets. `1` is a value rather than a type, so can't be used in this context. (Edit: depending on how the generic type is defined, it might expect more than one type parameter between the angle brackets, but that's not really relevant to this question, I'm just mentioning it for completeness).

I suspect what you want instead is either a `List<int>` (see documentation for [List<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-7.0)), or an `int[]` ([array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array?view=net-7.0) of integers). An array is good if you know exactly what it should contain at the point when you create it. A `List<T>` is more useful if you want to add and remove items after it is created.

If you decide arrays are what you want then your code would look like this:

```
var requestBody = new microsoft.Graph.Drives.Item.Items.Item.Workbook.Tables.Item.Rows.Add.AddPostRequestBody
{
    Index = 5,
    Values = new int[][]
    {
        new int[] { 1, 2, 3 },
        new int[] { 4, 5, 6 },
    },
};
```

If instead you want to use `List<T>` then your code would look like this:

```
var requestBody = new microsoft.Graph.Drives.Item.Items.Item.Workbook.Tables.Item.Rows.Add.AddPostRequestBody
{
    Index = 5,
    Values = new List<List<int>>
    {
        new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 },
        new List<int> { 4, 5, 6 },
    },
};
```

The fact that I've initialised each `int[]` / `List<int>` on a single line is not significant. If you prefer, you can continue to have each number in a line on its own as per your original code.

But you're not constrained to an array of arrays of integers (`int[][]`) or a list of lists of integers (`List<List<int>>`). If it suits your needs better then you could use a list of arrays of integers (`List<int[]>`) or an array of lists of integers (`List<int>[]`).

(Edit 2: Having seen the comment from @user2250152, it looks like this answer will only fix the syntax errors in the client code you copied from some example code which Microsoft appear to have since deleted. So your client should compile OK, but I can't guarantee that it'll be able to call the graph API correctly. I'll step back now and see if any people who actually know that API chip in)